# Changing the email address attached to an Apple Id

Tags: apple-id

How can I change the email address attached to my AppleId?

I have two iPad minis running Roomie software for Home automation, to control Audio/Visual devices. The iPads, the software and it's subscription are all tied to my AppleId and my credit card.

I am selling the house and I would have liked to keep the ApplieId, but Roomie are not responding to my question on how to change AppleIds on their software.  I am now thinking that perhaps I could just change the email address attached to the AppleId and try to cancel the subscription, closer to the time.

**From Comments** - The reason for the problem is that its part of the home automation.  The home is being marketed as fully automated.  What I have done with all the other non-Apple gear is to create a new Google email address and migrated everything over. Ideally, I would like the iPads and Roomie to also use the same email address.

If I just create a new account, I have to start from scratch and its quite a few days work to integrate it all into the home automation.  I can't do that as the home is still being viewed by potential buyers and the real estate agent vows the buyers by saying things like `Alexa start Living Fire`, `Start playing Movies` (which uses multiple techs to close the blinds, turn on the projector and players, switch channels, turn off lights etc.).  While it is being marketed, I can't start making drastic changes.  If I wait until the house has sold, I will not have enough time.

Comment: So cancel the subscription and take the AppleID with you.  If you are going to leave the hardware, the new owner can subscribe, or not, as they like.

Comment: @MarcWilson, I have added more information.  I can't just leave, its all integrated into the Home Automation.  It needs to be working when I leave.  Sure I can cancel the subscription, but that is still annoying for the new owner.  I want the new owner to have a smooth transition.  Its better to transfer it over.

Comment: From looking at the description of the software, I'm not even sure that changing the email address of an AppleID will help. Anyway, this seems to be primarily a question about how to hand over a roomie-managed home to a new owner. You might get better answers in the [Roomie Forum](https://forum.roomieremote.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple provides excellent instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/109353) on how to change the email address attached to an Apple ID.

Since you’re using an iPad below are the instructions on how to remove or change your email address associated with an Apple ID for iOS/iPadOS

> #### How to change your Apple ID email address on your iPhone or iPad
>
> 1. Go to Settings, then tap your name.
> 2. Tap Sign In & Security.
> 3. Next to Email & Phone Numbers, tap Edit.
> 4. Tap the Remove buttonRemove button next to the email address, then tap Delete.
> 5. Tap Choose Another Email Address and enter your device passcode if asked.
> 6. Enter the new email address, then tap Continue.
> 7. Enter the verification code that was sent to your new email address.

You can also change it via the web at appleid@apple.com

Comment: What happens to the installed Apps?  In particular `Roomie`, I need it to retain all its data and carry on working. I am more ofay with Android.  I had to use Roomie on iPad as there was nothing like it on Android.

Comment: Nothing happens to your installed apps.  But for a definitive answer, the folks who develop Roomie should be able to give you a clear answer